# How to display data if the device has no network connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsjsonserialization

I have a situation where I'm presenting data in a `UITableView` using `NSJSONSerialization` from an external source. I also have to show this data if the device is in offline mode. What is the best approach to doing this? Do I need an internal db to store the data, check for wifi and if it's unavailable present the local data?

thanks for any help or tutorials you may know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar requirement for an app I am working on. I am pulling the data from parse.com (remote objects) and put the data into core data (local objects). When presenting a table view, I run the parse.com query in the background, which pulls the data and puts it into core data. The table views use `NSFetchedResultsController` so when changes occur to the core data (local) objects, the table view is updated as the data is retrieved. If off line, nothing is retrieved, so the table view does not update, but is presenting the last update of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes . You can make local database to do that thing.

You can check the wifi status. If net connection is available than display data from the external source  and if net connection is not available than display data from the local database.

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve data from external source when you are online store it locally.
Next time when your app is launched:

- Check for network connection
- If network connection is available retrieve data and re-write the old content
- If network connection is not available use the locally stored data

Data can be stored in `plist`, `database file` or as an `text file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **CoreData database** i.e. and update the data every time you connect. If you cannot connect, just show the old data.

How to use and how to check WiFi connection SO is offering more than enought content ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in plist if it is not too much.

```
-(void)Writetoplist:(NSMutableDictionary*)LoginDetails
```

{

```
 {
    //////// This is used to delete the plist file if exist //////
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LoginDetails.plist"];

 NSError *error;
  if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:&error])
        {
            //TODO: Handle/Log error
        }

        /// to write the SP Details in plist file
        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our plist ("Documents/foo.plist")
        plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LoginDetails.plist"];
        [LoginDetails writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
       }
```

}